# Why does this force close before the activity screen is drawn? (android)

Tags: android

my app keeps force closing before it starts... eclipse returns no errors in my code and my xml is good. can anybody give me some insight?

```
package com.mhe.test.scan;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button myScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myScanButton);         
          myScanButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

               }
            });
    }


    EditText totalbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalbox);
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                    // Handle successful scan
                    totalbox.setText(contents);
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // Handle cancel
                    totalbox.setText("@string/bummer");
                }



            }      
         }
    }
```

essentially it is supposed to call zxing Barcode Scanner to scan a barcode on a button click and return the result into an EditText field... i'm a total newbie at this...

Comment: And wheres the logcat output?

Comment: well Cristian... perhaps the term newbie was not descriptive enough... i am really just learning all this the past few days, and desperately trying to piece together a demo to show to my boss who says it's a "top priority". android looked like the easiest way to go on a mobile device, so off i went. I will have help in a few weeks. How do i get the logcat?

Comment: your answer fixed FC ryan, i just can't figure out how to pass the Scan result into my EditText... more digging to be done i guess

Comment: scratch that... that worked. tried to test it in a new file and forgot to change other stuff... worked like a charm thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
EditText totalbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalbox);
```

Is not in the OnCreate method, so its trying to initialize the totalbox before the activity is created, probably causing the crash

Try this instead:

```
package com.mhe.test.scan;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class main extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button myScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myScanButton); 
    // set the totalbox in the onCreate
    totalbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalbox);        
    myScanButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
      }
    });
  }

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        // Handle successful scan
        // check that it exists, just in case
        if ( totalbox != null )
          totalbox.setText(contents);
      } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Handle cancel
        // check that it exists, just in case
        if ( totalbox != null )
          totalbox.setText("@string/bummer");
      }
    }      
  }

  private EditText totalbox;
}
```